# How can I enable shading in texture mode?

Tags: texturing

I've been looking for a solution for about 45min and I can't find it anywhere (on the internet too). In texture mode, the object has no shading and I can't recognize any shape, which makes it impossible to texture paint.

Solid mode:
[image]

The same frame in texutre paint mode:
[image]

Here's after following the tutorial. At the point, he had shading "on". I did the steps in the video with smart UV project, adding a material that way and so forth:
[image]

Comment: Hello, is anyone there? What about the people who are around here and work with texture paint successfully? How do you do that? I can't imagine every single person here doesn't know how to use texture paint...

Answer (score 1):

I've asked this question on a discord server where I got a one-line answer that solved the problem within 20 minutes.

**Solution:** Disable any overlays in the 3D viewport. When you take a closer look at some of the problem pictures, you'll find the overlays enabled. Here's what it looks like when they are turned off:
[image]